# Suppose $A_n \supset A_{n+1}$ . Show $P(A_n) \searrow P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I know the proof for if it is a monotonic increasing sequence of sets using the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(B_i)$ goes to 0, where $B_i$ is a partition of ${A_i}$.

Comment: it seems you've messed up the statement, it should be a decreasing sequence convergent to the probability of intersection of $A_n$'s

Comment: You are correct. Sorry, I changed it. The question still remains.

Comment: Thank you. I'm really bad at knowing what to search for!